# How to Implement Splash Animation in Unity for iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

In latest Unity 5, having option to import XIB file as Splash Screen. In XIB, we can do animation of Splash Screen.

[image]

--main.storyboard

--Check Build Setting of iOS in Unity 5